# Adjusting border around image requires changing height and width

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following image with a circular border. I want to be able to change the size (diameter) of the border but in order to do so I have to change the width and height of the image in addition to the border.  Is it possible to change the border size without having to change the other attributes as well?  Here is my html and css class. Thanks.

```
<div><img class="marker"></div>

.marker {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    transform: rotate(50deg) !important;
    position: absolute;
    border:solid 50px rgba(50, 105, 206, 0.5);
    border-radius:150px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

[image: map marker]

Comment: Why would you have to change the size of the image?

Comment: If you want to change the border size, just change the border property. eg: border:solid 100px rgba(50, 105, 206, 0.5);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset the element's `box-sizing` property to the default `content-box`.

Most likely you have some CSS elsewhere that is changing it to `border-box`

```css
.marker {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transform: rotate(50deg) !important;
  /* position: absolute; */
  border: solid 50px rgba(50, 105, 206, 0.5);
  border-radius: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.marker-alt {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div><img class="marker"></div>

<div><img class="marker marker-alt"></div>
```

Comment: If the image height and width are not increased the outer circle diameter stays the same and the image is shrunk in the middle.

Comment: Changing the box sizing and border-radius to a large value together did the trick.

Comment: You can use `border-radius: 50%` then you don't have to worry about changing the value if your elements dimensions change.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve what you want, replace your border property with this:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(50, 105, 206, 0.5);
```

With this, you can change the size of the "border" by changing the spread option in the box-shadow property (i.e. the `50px` value).

See my example: https://jsbin.com/viyihah/edit?html,css,output

You can read more about the `box-shadow` property on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow, but essentially the first 3 properties that I've set to `0` are offset-x, offset-y and blur-radius (thus the shadow will be centered on the element and won't appear blurred, but solid) while the `50px` value is the spread-radius, which essentially determines the size of the "border." The last value is simply the color.

Answer (score 0):

you can play with `border-width` and `border-radius:50%;` to make it round every time

```css
.marker {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    transform: rotate(50deg) !important;
    position: relative;
    border:solid 100px rgba(50, 105, 206, 0.5);
    border-radius:50%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .marker.sm{
    border-width: 10px;

  }
```

```html
<div><img class="marker" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/04/22/35/head-659652_960_720.png"></div>


<div><img class="marker sm" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/04/22/35/head-659652_960_720.png"></div>
```